# extracting particular numbers from text file and conversion to year month and day

Tags: scripts

For example I have a data file like;

```
joze0670.14o
joze0680.14o
joze0690.14o
```

I need to extract 3 digits (day of the year) after the first 4 characters and 2 digits (year starts with 2000) before "o". Then I want to find year-month-day for each data and assign these to variable.

Let say, `doy_1=067;year_1=2014` for the first data. Then the variables are assigned; `year=2014;month=03;day=08`

I will use these variables within loop later (like $year, $month, $day).

What is the proper way to these process?

Comment: Do those data lines always contain "joze" or that could be any text ?

Comment: it would be any 4 characters text

Comment: Ok, working on a solution. Will post in couple of minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `sed`, `xargs` and `date`:

```
$ sed -r 's/.{4}([0-9]{3}).*/\1/' input | xargs -i date -d '2014-01-01 + {} days - 1 day' '+%Y %m %d'
2014 03 08
2014 03 09
2014 03 10
```

Then you can `read` the values into variables:

```bsh
sed -r 's/.{4}([0-9]{3}).*/\1/' input | xargs -i date -d '2014-01-01 + {} days - 1 day' '+%Y %m %d' | 
  while read year month day
  do
     echo "Year: $year"
     echo "Month: $month"
     echo "Day: $day"
  done
```

References:

- [How to convert from day of year and year to a date YYYYMMDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/231692/how-to-convert-from-day-of-year-and-year-to-a-date-yyyymmdd)

---

The previous code used a fixed year. To use the year given by the extension, we can tell `sed` to create a complete date string for `date`:

```
sed -r 's/.{4}([0-9]{3}).\.([0-9]{2}).*/20\2-01-01 + \1 days - 1 day/' input | xargs -i date -d {} '+%Y %m %d'
```

Comment: @muzu it gives this error;sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown option to `s'

Comment: input file is the text file which contain data, right?

Comment: ok @muru, I just run second part of your codes, it worked well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @fedorqui adapted to use the year from the extension.

Comment: I just realized that your script only works if all data within 2014 but the data can be start from 2000.

Comment: @deepblue_86 fedorqui pointed that out and I have already updated accordingly.

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: when I run your last updated example, the scripts cannot be ended on the command line.

Comment: @deepblue_86 Eh? What do you mean?

Comment: When I run your last updated code (sed -r 's/.{4}([0-9]{3}).\.([0-9]{2}).*/20\2-01-01 + \1 days - 1 day/' input | xargs -i date -d {} '+%Y %m %d') on terminal, dates are ordered what it supposed to be but slash is still blinking. It like, script is waiting response

Comment: @deepblue_86 cannot reproduce. I think you're messing up the command somehow - otherwise why would you have got the sed error you mentioned in the first comment? Fix your copy pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Via this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r line; do 
    year=$(sed 's/^.\{4,4\}\([0-9]\{3,3\}\)0\.\(.*\)o/\1 \2/' <(echo "$line") | awk '{system("date -d \"01/01/"$2" +"$1" days -1 days\" +\"%Y\"")}')
    month=$(sed 's/^.\{4,4\}\([0-9]\{3,3\}\)0\.\(.*\)o/\1 \2/' <(echo "$line") | awk '{system("date -d \"01/01/"$2" +"$1" days -1 days\" +\"%m\"")}')
    day=$(sed 's/^.\{4,4\}\([0-9]\{3,3\}\)0\.\(.*\)o/\1 \2/' <(echo "$line") | awk '{system("date -d \"01/01/"$2" +"$1" days -1 days\" +\"%d\"")}')
done <foo
```

---

*Example*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r line; do 
    year=$(sed 's/^.\{4,4\}\([0-9]\{3,3\}\)0\.\(.*\)o/\1 \2/' <(echo "$line") | awk '{system("date -d \"01/01/"$2" +"$1" days -1 days\" +\"%Y\"")}')
    month=$(sed 's/^.\{4,4\}\([0-9]\{3,3\}\)0\.\(.*\)o/\1 \2/' <(echo "$line") | awk '{system("date -d \"01/01/"$2" +"$1" days -1 days\" +\"%m\"")}')
    day=$(sed 's/^.\{4,4\}\([0-9]\{3,3\}\)0\.\(.*\)o/\1 \2/' <(echo "$line") | awk '{system("date -d \"01/01/"$2" +"$1" days -1 days\" +\"%d\"")}')

    echo "$year"
    echo "$month"
    echo "$day"
done <foo
```

gives the output

```
2014
03
08
2014
03
09
2014
03
10
```

Answer (score 1):

**Basic Idea**

Unix epoch time operates on seconds. The script bellow extracts a year, converts the first day of the year to the unix epoch time, offsets it by (86400 seconds per day ) * (days extracted - 1), and converts it back to human readable format

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
SECONDSINYEAR=86400

while  read line && [[ -n $line ]];do
   ARRAY=( $( awk -F '.' '!/^$/{gsub(/[a-z,A-Z]/,""); print substr($1,1,3),$2 }' <<< "$line") )
   ARRAY[0]=$( expr ${ARRAY[0]} - 1  )
   DAYOFFSET=$( expr ${ARRAY[0]} \* 86400 )
   BASEDATE=$(date -d ${ARRAY[1]}0101 +%s)
   ACTUALDATE=$( expr $BASEDATE + $DAYOFFSET )

   date -d "@$ACTUALDATE" +%d" "%m" "%Y

done  < $1
```

**Output**

```
xieerqi:$ cat testFile.txt                                                
joze0670.14o
joze0680.14o
joze0690.14o


xieerqi:$ ./extractDate.sh testFile.txt                                   
08 03 2014
09 03 2014
10 03 2014
```

Comment: `cat file | while ...` can be simplified to `while read ... do ... done < file`. Note also that awk's default field separator (both for input and output) is the space, so `print substr() " " $2` can be simplified to `print substr(), $2`. Also, `printf "$line" | awk '...'` can be written as `awk '...' <<< "$line"`.

Comment: @fedorqui thank you, adding these to the script right now

Comment: And if you're using `bash`, there is no reason to use `$(expr ...)`. Just do `$((${ARRAY[0]} - 1))`, `$((${ARRAY[0]} * 86400))`, etc.

Comment: @muru I tried, but I kept getting syntax errors. How much spacing there should be between first and second bracket ?

Comment: @Serg none at all. `$(( ))` is bash for [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html).

Comment: In fact, you can rely on variable expansion within in `$(( ))`, so: `$((ARRAY[0] - 1))`, `$((ARRAY[0] * 86400))` would work as expected.

Comment: @muru Ok, but now there's a small problem, each day value is treated as octal `./extractDate.sh: line 7: 068: value too great for base (error token is "068")`

Comment: @Serg Ah, that annoying problem. Yes: `$((10#${ARRAY[0]} - 1))` will force `ARRAY[0]` to be interpreted in base 10.

Comment: See: [how to suppress bash octal number interpretation? (to be interpreted as decimal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70972)

Comment: `./extractDate.sh: line 7: ARRAY[0]#10 - 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "#10 - 1")` I think expr seems to be a little more simpler to use :)